# when "am start" a activity,what the "total time" mean?

Tags: android, adb

I launch a activity use:

```
am start -W -n
```

The console output：

```
tangbincheng@tangbinchengdeMacBook-Pro:~$ adb shell

shell@hwp6-t00:/ $ su

root@hwp6-t00:/ # am start -W -n com.book2345.reader/com.book2345.reader.MainA>

Starting: Intent { cmp=com.book2345.reader/.MainActivity }

Status: ok

Activity: com.book2345.reader/.MainActivity

ThisTime: 1554

TotalTime: 42815

Complete
```

what the `ThisTime` and the `TotalTime` mean?

Comment: why do you want to start an Activity in this way?

Answer (score 1):

search in android source code:
You can find "thisTime/totalTime"

"**thisTime**": just current activity launched time

"**totalTime**":the activity you started may be on the bottom of activity stack. So it refers to the total time from activity searching to current activity launched.

```
final long thisTime = curTime - displayStartTime;
final long totalTime = stack.mLaunchStartTime != 0
        ? (curTime - stack.mLaunchStartTime) : thisTime;
```