# What is the difference between ThisTime & TotalTime? why some times both values are equal, some times different?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, adb, android-testing

We can able to measure the launching time of any app using "adb shell am start -w -n yourpackagename/.activityname" (Wait for launch to complete). This adb shell command will print TotalTime & ThisTime.

But I have following questions?

- What is the difference between TotalTime & ThisTime?
- What is the right metric to measure the performance ? ThisTime or TotalTime ?
- Why sometimes both ThisTime & TotalTime values are equal? why sometimes both are different ?

**Example:**

```
adb shell am start -W -n com.android.settings/.ApplicationSettings
ThisTime: 1554
TotalTime: 42815
```

Comment: check this question, could be what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736882/when-am-start-a-activity-what-the-total-time-mean

Comment: Thanks Yazan,So the TotalTime is the right metric to measure app performance? when stack.mLaunchStartTime will return zero (both ThisTime & TotalTime equal)?

Comment: i am not pretty sure about this, as the answer says `totalTime` includes other periods of time needed for other tasks related to launch the activity, but not the launch operation itself, so totalTime could change according to the nature of these tasks, like when answer says time consumed in search (if the activity is in the bottom of the stack) what if it was not at the bottom? what if the stack was larger some times? this will make totalTime larger, but that does not mean the activity itself is slow, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, look at the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736882/when-am-start-a-activity-what-the-total-time-mean) question

> **"thisTime"**: just current activity launched time
>
> **"totalTime"**:the activity you started may be on the bottom of activity stack. So it refers to the total time from activity searching
>   to current activity launched.